# Matplotlib plot will not close

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib in python3 to plot results obtained and appended into an array. The function which hold all the plot details is shown below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from drawnow import *
import time
from time import sleep

plt.ion()

def plotgainC():
    plt.ylim(0,10)
    plt.xlim(0,3)
    plt.title('S11')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.ylabel('Magnitude Ratio')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency / GHz')
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0.1,2.7,43),gainC, 'rx-', label='dBm')
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')


gainC = np.array([1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 7, 8, 4, 8, 9, 6, 5, 4, 8, 6, 8, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 3, 2])
drawnow(plotgainC)

time.sleep(1)

plt.close() #didn't work

plt.close('all') #didn't work either
```

I've tried using multiple ways to close the plot.

`plt.close()`, `plt.close(plotgainC)`, `plt.close(1)` and `plt.close('all')`

None of these seem to close the plot. No error is shown either. Nothing happens when these close commands are run. Any idea why?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. `plt.close()` does the job for me.

Comment: I think you would want to come up with a [mcve] of the issue, such that people have the chance to reproduce this. In addition to the actual code one would need a clear guide on how you run this and which versions are in use.

Comment: @anishtain4 I added a more complete code. I ran this and it recreates the issue. If I'm not mistaken the plot should close in 1 second right? It does not happen.

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.ion(); plt.plot([1,2,3,4]); plt.close()` works fine for me. Can you reduce it down to that?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest it's a python3 code running on Thonny IDE on a Raspberry Pi. Ideally, I should see the plot close in 1 second right?

Comment: I'm always a bit sceptical about `drawnow`. Would it be possible to get rid of that?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I will try that out ASAP